# Using illuminate/pagination outside laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, illuminate-container

I'm building custom project and for now for database connection i used illuminate/database the eloquent model.
But i need samo pagination to continue my development i installed via composer illuminate/pagination and i cant configure it propertly i searched all over the internet no documentation for using with illuminate pagination or how to configure it.

I have function

```
User::all();
```

Where i fetch all my users successfully but i need to make paginate when i try to use ->paginate() method not found.

The composer is set coorectly and all my files are loaded.

Any tips how to set up the illuminate/pagination library ?
Btw i developed custom framework where i have controller and models. All my models are Eloquent models.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone ? I need this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the forPage() method on the Collection itself.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forpage

This worked for me:

```
$collection->forPage($_GET["pagenr"], $perpage);
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't use illuminate/pagination for this use-case. It is much easier to implement what you want with forPage() method.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
composer require illuminate/pagination
```

**for example :** if need Controllers and Models add autoload psr-4

> composer.json

```
{
 "name": "illuminate-example/eloquent",
 "description": "Implementation of Database Queries with illuminate and Eloquent",
 "type": "project",
 "require": {
 "illuminate/database": "^6.17",
  "illuminate/pagination": "^6.17"},
 "autoload":
    {"psr-4":
        { "Controllers\\": "app/controllers/",
            "Models\\": "app/models/"

                 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is helpful anymore, but I was having the same issue and came across this: https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-paginator-does-not-exist-laravel-42

Seems as though it's not possible outside laravel.